# map inside map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, stdmap

I have a difficult time creating nested maps in C++.

First of all I have typedefed my types

```
typedef std::map<std::variant<int, std::string>, std::variant<int, long long int, std::string>> SimpleDict;
typedef std::map<std::variant<int, std::string>, std::variant<int, std::string,std::vector<SimpleDict>,SimpleDict>> ComplexDict;
```

Then I define my map:

```
ComplexDict m = {
        "MAC0", {

                {"TAG0", "111001011000"},
                {"SEQ", "110000100100"},
                {"IOD", "0000"}

        }

};
```

However I get `No matching constructor for initialization of 'ComplexDic`. Even if I change the type of m to `std::map< std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string> >` for simplicity, I get the same error. I think I'm doing something wrong with the syntax. Could you help?

Comment: Whats that `"MAC0",` ? Maybe you are just missing a set of braces. In your example the map should be initialized with a single element?

Comment: You are missing one pair of brackets: https://godbolt.org/z/7nGaWPxWz (which represent a single element of the outer map).

Comment: Side note: if you are trying to roll your own JSON parser, I suggest using one of existing libraries. It's quite a difficult task.

Comment: Explanation: Internally `std::map` stores its contents in form of `std::pair<key_type, value_type>`s. If you want to initialise a map, you need to provide such pairs, too: `ComplexDict m = { std::pair<key_type, value_type>("MAC0", { /* your map */ }) };` The pair doesn't need to be specified explicitly, you can profit from uniform initialisation again – this is done via the *additional pair* of braces, as preceding comments showed already.

Comment: You are right guys, I was missing a pair of braces. @Yksisarvinen Do you have to suggest a specific library?

Comment: Unrelated, `std::variant` is not standard-compliant to C++11, or even C++14. It was introduced in C++17, so the tagging on this post is questionable.

Comment: @WhozCraig std::variant is not related to the core of the question. In the simple form, I didn't used std::variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, you miss one set of braces to denote "a pair in top level map":

```
typedef std::map< std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string> > ComplexDict2;
ComplexDict2 m = {
    { //first pair of map
        "MAC0", {
            {"TAG0", "111001011000"},
            {"SEQ", "110000100100"},
            {"IOD", "0000"}
        }
    } //first pair end
};
```

---

For the actual case with variants, it seems that compiler is confused what type should this be:

```
{
    {"TAG0", "111001011000"},
    {"SEQ", "110000100100"},
    {"IOD", "0000"}
}
```

You can resolve it by naming the type explicitly:

```
ComplexDict m = {
    {
        "MAC0", SimpleDict {
            {"TAG0", "111001011000"},
            {"SEQ", "110000100100"},
            {"IOD", "0000"}
        }
    }
};
```